# Ruby win32ole - Can't replace text in word document

Tags: ruby, windows, ms-word, win32ole

I'm trying to replace text in a document like so:

```
require 'win32ole'

def replace_doc(doc, find, repl)
    begin
        word = WIN32OLE.new('Word.Application')
        word.Visible = true
        doc = word.Documents.Open(doc)

        word.Selection.HomeKey(unit=6)
        finder = word.Selection.Find
        finder.Text = "[#{find}]"

        while word.Selection.Find.Execute
            word.Selection.TypeText(text=repl)
        end

        doc.SaveAs(doc)
        doc.Close
    rescue Exception => e
        puts e.message
        puts "Unable to edit file."
    end
end

def main()
    puts "File: "
    doc = gets.chomp()

    puts "Find: "
    find = gets.chomp()

    puts "Replace with: "
    repl = gets.chomp()

    replace_doc(doc, find, repl)
end

main()
```

I'm running Ruby 2.0 on Windows XP. The WINWORD.exe process starts (I see it in task manager), and no exception is raised. However, when I go to the document, none of the text I expect to be replaced -- is. What is going on? I've copied the code (except for a few things) from [here](http://mpov.timmorgan.org/find-andamp-replace-in-word-with-ruby/).

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say without the actual word document and input data you're using, but I suspect that the square brackets in `finder.Text` are your issue.  As your program is now, entering `foo` for the find text would search for `[foo]` in your word document, not plain `foo`.  Note that in the post you linked. There are actual square brackets in the example word document (it contains `[date]` etc.)